# Qbasic interpreter for cpp

Tags: c++, vbscript, qbasic

I like to embed QBasic or some subset of VBscript alike script in cpp app .
is there any such thing ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the ScriptControl ([1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc302278.aspx), [2](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/229669/en-us)) or implement an ActiveScriptHost ([1](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2830/Macro-Scripting-Language-Support-MFC), [2](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/349554/Cplusplus-Win-and-Scripting-Quick-way-to-add-Scr))

**Update:** If you need cross-platform scripting, consider to use Perl, Python, Lua, QTScript, ... instead of Basic.

Comment: i need it cross platform